# Any way to get the underlying webrtcDataChannel object from a vline person or channel?

Tags: vline

I would like access to the underlying webRTC datachannel object, do you have an API for this? If not, how can this be handled? This is a deal breaker as I need features you have not implemented, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently expose the WebRTC DataChannel because reliable (SCTP-based) data channels are not yet enabled by default in the currently stable Chrome (i.e., it is behind a flag). There are also issues with Chrome and Firefox interop: https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=2279.